# conversion of json

Tags: php, json

hi guys i'm working to show weather updates on my website.
for that i'm sending some code which is returning me some thing like below

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [current_condition] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [temp_C] => 26
                            [temp_F] => 79
                        )



                )
        )
)
```

i want to fetch the temp_C which is somewhere beneath [o]=>stdClass Object
for that purpose i used the statment like this

```
//$returning is variable have all the json in it
$celcius = $returning->data->current_condition->0->temp_c;
```

kindly guide me how to get temp_C,,,i'm currently working with php.
Thankx to all

Comment: i will read it dear ,,but in free time,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`current_condition` is an array

```
$celcius = $returning->data->current_condition[0]->temp_c;
```